# iOS phonegap app built mainly on AJAX calls

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, mobile, app-store

I am thinking about architecture of my new iOS app. I don't know how much of the parts of the app build as native parts of the app and how much dynamically loaded via AJAX calls.

For example admin area. I can create all the admin area as native part and load only data via AJAX. But If I want to add another form field later I will have to publish update of the application. I can avoid this by loading all the admin area via AJAX calls (not only data but also HTML structure). It would be very flexible. But it would increase amount of transferred data and I don't know if this is acceptable for Apple.

Is this structure of highly AJAX called app okey for Apple?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I have just added exact question - "Is this structure of highly AJAX called app okey for Apple?"

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need worry because my app has same structure than you, it loads some data via AJAX and I had no problems on App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can build an app like so, but this would result in a higher download for your users later on.

I agree that building an app in that way might be a solution to stop going past Apple for every update.

Kind regards,